# Running Impala query from shell script

Tags: shell, impala

I want to write a shell script to invoke an Impala query. I want to check count of a table is 0 or not. If 0, then I need to fail the workflow.
I am pretty new to shell script, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share, what did you try so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have my code as follows:-   #!/bin/bash

impala -e "select count(*) from table1" >select.txt

result=`echo $?`

if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then

mail -s "Workflow failure" abc@gmail.com <<< "Workflow failure because of 0 records in table"

echo "We have an Error!!!!"

exit 1

else

impala -e "insert into table2 values ('api_bu',$result,now())" >insert.txt


fi   The insert is not happening.